# asp.net form is not getting submitted when "onsubmit" event calls a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, dom-events

The situation is :

I want to disable all the controls on the page (possibly using an overlayed div), on the submit of a form, so that the user cannot click on other buttons, till the page is still processing the postback. So, I used the form's `onsubmit` event to call a Javascript function that does the same. But now that function is being called, but the form do not get posted at all. I even tried, using `return true;` as the last line of my JavaScript function, but still the form does not get posted.
This is my Javascript function :

```
function DoThis() 
    {
        alert('this form is about to be submitted...');
        return true;
    }
```

and this is my form tag:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" onsubmit="DoThis();">
```

What's is wrong here? Also, let me know if there is some other way that would serve my purpose?

EDIT : I'm not referring to ajax calls here, since `updatepanels` already have features to enable this behaviour. I want this functionality for the entire page, even when a button outside an update panel is clicked resulting into full-postback and not just for ajax-calls (since the user normally has sufficient time to click 2 or 3 buttons, by the time the page get's redirected or reloaded).

Comment: I have tested this in IE8 and FF8.01 and it works. I think a better approach would be to attach the js event to the onclientclick of the submit button itself and show the overlay div in that event.

Comment: does the form gets posted back??? In my case, it doesn't. I too am using IE8.

Comment: yes it does. does ur page have update panels in it.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Through a series of hit-n-trials, I finally figured out that I was missing the "return" keyword to add in my form tag. So, I modified my form tag as :

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" onsubmit="return DoThis();">
```

Silly things eat a lot of time. Probably, **in-experience**.

Comment: That's hasn't solved the issue for me, it's still not firing button events.

Comment: Yes, I did. In the end I used jQuery to attach an event on form submit, somehow it worked this time around, while failing previously. I think it may have had something to do with me also trying to attach onSubmit script from code-behind in basepage, which I also removed now.

Comment: This answer saved me some time (I use the variation onsubmit="DoThis(); return true;"). Funny thing is: with two forms designed the same way, both including the same script manager, this correction was needed for one but not for the other.

Comment: How is this different from the first suggestion in [Elias's Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8603875/18192)?

Answer (score 5):

Would you please try any below way:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" onsubmit="return DoThis();" >
```

OR

```
function DoThis() 
    {
        alert('this form is about to be submitted...');
        this.submit();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

of course `onsubmit` wouldn't work with asp.net.

I solved it with very easy way.

if we have such a form

```
<form method="post" name="setting-form" >
   <input type="text" id="UserName" name="UserName" value="" 
      placeholder="user name" >
   <input type="password" id="Password" name="password" value="" placeholder="password" >
   <div id="remember" class="checkbox">
    <label>remember me</label>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server" />
   </div>
   <input type="submit" value="login" id="login-btn"/>
</form>
```

You can now catch get that event before the form postback and stop it from  postback and do all the ajax you want using this jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#login-btn").click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                alert("do what ever you want");
            });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        function testSubmit(form) {
            form.submit();
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <form action="http://www.yahoo.com" id="myForm" onsubmit="testSubmit(this)" >
    First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" /><br />
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" />
    <input type="submit"  value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: but this case works only when there is only one submit button. There are a lot of postback-making sources(like gridview rows) for which a postback occurs. But if you do, **form.submit**, then the current page gets submitted(or in other words, **simply gets reloaded**).

Answer (score -1):

in 'DoThis' function add 'this.submit()'

`function DoThis() {
            alert('this form is about to be submitted...');
            this.submit();
        }`

I havent tested this. Please check.

Are you using any js libraries like JQuery ?

Comment: didn't work.Error message says : **this.submit() is not a function, as this refers to window object.** yes, I'm using jQuery.